# (De-)Serialize Json to C# in StoredProcedure

Tags: c#, json, stored-procedures, .net-4.0, sql-server-2014

my problem is that I can't use the jsonserializer class from System.Web.Extensions or any NuGet packages to convert my json/c# objects because I want to do it within stored procedures on the server.

It's a sql server 2014 running .net 4.0.

I already tried to add the assembly as unsafe but can't get it to work because of the assemblies it depends on (or references).

So now my questions is if anyone of you knows if there is a already implemented class I could use or if I have to write my own json serializer.

Thanks for your help

Edit: Sorry for not being clear enough.

With "convert" I meant serializing an deserializing. Normally I would use the jsonserializer class but what could I use in a stored procedure?

Comment: JSON is a data format and C# is a programming language so I have no idea what “Convert Json to C# and back” is supposed to mean. If you must do whatever it is you're trying to do in a stored procedure, why are you using C# and not TSQL?

Comment: Why not store the JSON in the SQL and use C# to convert it?  Or use C# to deserialze it into an object and use the data from that object passed into the stored procedure?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I edited my post to be clearer on what I meant. My problem is the (de) serialization in a stored procedure

Comment: JSON is a data format and C# is a programming language so I have no idea what “(De-)Serialize Json to C# in StoredProcedure” is supposed to mean. Please post sample JSON and what “(De-)Serialize” output you want.

Comment: So here is my sample Json:
`{"PersonID":123456,"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Test","Street":"street","StreetNumber":"14","ZipCode":"12345","City":"CityName",}`  
    
After deserisalization it should be a instance of this object:  
  
`public class Person  
{  
    public int PersonID { get; set; }  
    public string FirstName { get; set; }  
    public string LastName { get; set; }  
    public string Street { get; set; }  
    public string StreetNumber { get; set; }  
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }  
    public string City { get; set; }  
}`

Answer (score 0):

Are you in a position to be able to look at using the next version of SQL server?
It contains some JSON support that 2014 does not.
Without knowing more about what you're trying to do I can't really comment further. You say you want to do it, not sure exactly what 'it' is in the case, in stored procedures, but not why. Are you serialising or de-serialising?

See the following for more details: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jocapc/archive/2015/05/16/json-support-in-sql-server-2016.aspx

Comment: I will definitely look into it but I can't say if I am allowed to upgrade the server to 2016. For now I'll have to find a solution for sql server 2014